# Ways to visualize current return paths on a PCB board

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, current-measurement

## Overview

I'm writing a paper on PCB layout, and included with the paper are some evaluation boards. Generally the boards demonstrate different layout concepts (bypass-caps, trace widths, controlled impedances). I want a board that can show current return paths at various frequencies.

Pictures below show an example of the board and the general current returns at low/high freq. What would be really useful is a way to see the current as frequency changes. Is there a good method to measure the current flowing along the plane? And by measure I mean just generally knowing where most of the current is flowing, there is no percent error spec. I have two thoughts, but am open to more.

### Method 1:

Place small resistors (mΩ range) on the plane and have a current shunt amplifier measure current though them. Would have to cut up plane a bit but would give voltages that could be probed and observed

### Method 2:

Pass a large current (>1Amp) through the board and measure heat on 2nd layer with a thermal camera. This would be a bit more expensive but I think it would give some nice looking results. I'd be a bit worried about the heat from the top layer propagating down but that could be mitigated with a thick trace or maybe even a wire folded down close to the board that emulates a trace.

### Pictures and Inspiration

Idea comes from this tutorial (figure 10-12, also shown below). Those picture are simulated though.

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/5/5450.html

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Method 3 - Scalpel, silver paint, and Teledeltos paper ( a Bob Pease classic) https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21776001/whats-all-this-teledeltos-stuff-anyway

Comment: Electroluminescent paint maybe???

Comment: The sims shown use a tool called a *field solver*. Ansoft, Cadence and others offer these rather expensive packages. There may be open-source solvers, or you may try to get a student eval from one of those guys.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank for the link, I will investigate that. It seems like I could fashion that paper into a mock ground plane and then probe different squares to find voltage drops. Low voltage drop indicating low current.

Comment: @KyleB I looked up Electroluminescent paint and it seems to activate from relatively high AC voltage (~100V), which I want to avoid in a lab setting. Would need special supervision and safety considerations. Thank you for the suggestion though